# Adding accessing getSummary within a paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

I'm using the Paragraph module as part of Drupal 8.

I have the following method to load the individual paragraphs when i match on a certain type

```
  try {
  $query = \Drupal::service('entity.query')->get('paragraph');
  $query->condition('type', $type);
  $paragraph_ids = $query->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  throw new \Exception('cannot get paragraphs of type: ' . $type);
}
```

subsequent to this, I loop through each $paragraph and check the results of

```
$paragraph->getSummaryItems()['content']
```

and filter accordingly.

What i'm looking to do is a more efficient way of filtering the entity by adding an additional condition on the $query 
eg

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('paragraph');
$query->condition('type', $type);
$query->condition($field, $value, $operator);
$paragraph_ids = $query->execute();
```

whilst this query works fine for a text or integer, i am having some real issues trying to get it to filter when adding a taxonomy term which is associated with the paragraph.

As i know the values i am trying to filter (and can see them in the content of the getSummaryItems()['content'] array), is there a way to add a filter that can give me access to this getSummaryItems()?

Alternatively, is there any documentation to describe how to add a condition to reference a taxonomy term attached to a paragraph?

Comment: For the alternative it'll be `$query->condition('field_name.target_id', $value, $operator);`. I'm not sure you can filter on the summary items